Polars Transform String Containing Key-Values
Trying to figure out how to transform a k-v string that is inside a column where the k-v string is separated by commas, and could contain different keys. The different keys would then be transformed into their own columns, where missing values would contain nulls.
For example,
pl.DataFrame({
    "apple": [1, 2, 3],
    "data": ["a=b, b=c", "a=y, y=z", "k1=v1, k2=v2"]
})

would look like:
pl.DataFrame({
    "apple": [1, 2, 3],
    "a": ["b", "y", None],
    "b": ["c", None, None],
    "y": [None, "z", None],
    "k1": [None, None, "v1"],
    "k2": [None, None, "v2"],
    "data": ["a=b, b=c", "a=y, y=z", "k1=v1, k2=v2"]
})

once transformed. Does anyone know what is the most efficient way to do this (perhaps without pre-processing of the data, if possible?)


You could attempt to reformat it as JSON objects.
df.with_columns(pl.format('{"{}"}', 
    pl.col("data").str.replace_many({"=": '":"', ", ": '","'})
))

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬──────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ apple ┆ data         ┆ literal               │
│ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---                   │
│ i64   ┆ str          ┆ str                   │
╞═══════╪══════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ a=b, b=c     ┆ {"a":"b","b":"c"}     │
│ 2     ┆ a=y, y=z     ┆ {"a":"y","y":"z"}     │
│ 3     ┆ k1=v1, k2=v2 ┆ {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"} │
└───────┴──────────────┴───────────────────────┘

Which would allow you to .str.json_decode() into a struct.
And then .unnest() into columns.
df.with_columns(
   pl.format('{"{}"}', 
      pl.col("data").str.replace_many({"=": '":"', ", ": '","'})
   )
   .str.json_decode()
   .alias("json")
).unnest("json")

shape: (3, 7)
┌───────┬──────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ apple ┆ data         ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ y    ┆ k1   ┆ k2   │
│ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64   ┆ str          ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═══════╪══════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1     ┆ a=b, b=c     ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 2     ┆ a=y, y=z     ┆ y    ┆ null ┆ z    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3     ┆ k1=v1, k2=v2 ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ v1   ┆ v2   │
└───────┴──────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘


Thanks - besides having to handle backslash escapes, this seems to be the most elegant solution. It also saves having to have a row index for a join and saves quite a bit of time having to flatten and then aggregate the data again.

The core data normalization you want goes as follows:
normalized = (
    df.with_columns(pl.col.data.str.split(", "))
    .explode("data")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.data.str.split_exact("=", 1).struct.rename_fields(["key", "val"])
    )
    .unnest("data")
)

Giving:
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ apple ┆ key ┆ val │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64   ┆ str ┆ str │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1     ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ 1     ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ 2     ┆ a   ┆ y   │
│ 2     ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ 3     ┆ k1  ┆ v1  │
│ 3     ┆ k2  ┆ v2  │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘

Then to mold it into the data shape you want:
>>> normalized.pivot("key", index="apple")
shape: (3, 6)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ apple ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ y    ┆ k1   ┆ k2   │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64   ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1     ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 2     ┆ y    ┆ null ┆ z    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ v1   ┆ v2   │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

Or if you really intended to have the data original string as well, you can just join it back on:
>>> normalized.pivot("key", index="apple").join(df, "apple")
shape: (3, 7)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────────────┐
│ apple ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ y    ┆ k1   ┆ k2   ┆ data         │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---          │
│ i64   ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str          │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a=b, b=c     │
│ 2     ┆ y    ┆ null ┆ z    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a=y, y=z     │
│ 3     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ v1   ┆ v2   ┆ k1=v1, k2=v2 │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────────────┘


Seems like it works for a small dataset, but on a dataset over 100k rows, it seems like it crashes Python on the pivot step, wanting to allocate more than 1 TB of memory:
15:53:29.186 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221226505, Reason: memory allocation of 1189863708480 bytes failed

@ChrisWong How many columns do you expect to have? Polars isn't particularly optimized for incredibly wide dataframes, it is a columnar-based library where the primary data axis is expected to be rows. 1TB sounds excessive though, if you can replicate that with a minimal reproducible example feel free to open a bug on the Github issue tracker.

about 170k x 85 -- I guess I will play around with it and see what can work. Thanks.

Just did a select so that only the specific columns with the k-v values were selected. After doing the split and before the pivot, the normalized dataframe was around 500k x 3, but Python still crashed with the same error: memory allocation of 1189863708480 bytes failed.

I am guessing this might have to do with the fact that one of the k-v's columns has a timestamp built-in, which probably causes a new column to be created for each row. I will try to optimize this somewhat and try again. Thanks!
